# https nginx 403 forbidden

Tags: node.js, nginx, centos

I create droplet on DigitalOcean, setup my nodeJS app on it, connected my domain and everything works ok, but I wanted to setup https andI installed all certificates etc. I run it on CentOS 7.5, my nodeJS app is in this directory:

```
/home/mdurakovic/mensurdurakovic.com
```

HTTP works fine, but I when I try to open my website with HTTPS I get error message in browser

```
403 Forbidden nginx/1.12.2
```

So I looked up in nginx logs and I see this error:

```
2019/01/02 23:03:39 [error] 11014#0: *1 directory index of "/home/mdurakovic/mensurdurakovic.com/public/" is forbidden, client: 213.149.62.113, server: mensurdurakovic.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "mensurdurakovic.com"
```

I changed group permissions so when I execute this command:

```
f: /home/mdurakovic/mensurdurakovic.com/public/
dr-xr-xr-x root       root  /
drwxr-xr-x root       root  home
drwx--x--- mdurakovic nginx mdurakovic
drwxrwxrwx nginx      nginx mensurdurakovic.com
drwxrwxrwx nginx      nginx public
```

As you can clearly see, nginx has rights to execute user's home dir, but it still doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/mensurdurakovic.com.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  mensurdurakovic.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://68.183.69.186:8080;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name mensurdurakovic.com;
    root /home/mdurakovic/mensurdurakovic.com/public;

    # certs sent to the client in SERVER HELLO are concatenated in ssl_certificate
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mensurdurakovic.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mensurdurakovic.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # intermediate configuration. tweak to your needs.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-$
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    resolver 8.8.8.8;
```

}

Comment: can you share your sites-enabled .conf file?

Comment: thank you for asking, I added my .conf file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having your http connection proxy the request, but not https.  If you add a block in your ssl config (and remove root and resolver)  it should work as expected:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://68.183.69.186:8080;
}
```